# How to Add REST API to Amplify v2 Android App?

Tags: android, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I cannot push my Amplify backend after performing `amplify add api` for REST APIs. I get the following IAM error in the CLI during the "Creating API models..." stage:

> User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/tb2-amplify is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/xxxxxxxxxx/stages/dev/sdks/android because no identity-based policy allows the apigateway:GET action

All I need is a public GET method to read an item from a DynamoDB table. My desired pipeline is `android -> Amplify.API.get() -> Lambda Function -> DynamoDB`. I have followed every guide available in the [Amplify Docs (Libraries/Guides)](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/android/), re-initialized Amplify in the project with API being the only resource, tried to manually add API to the `amplifyconfiguration.json` file. I am stumped.

**Is my desired pipeline the problem? Is there configuring I need to perform before `amplify push`? Does anyone know why my configured IAM is not authorized to do this, even though the permission has been granted?**

**UPDATE**

Granting my IAM user full administrator access allows me to `amplify push` the backend. I am now getting build errors like:

> package com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation does not exist
>
> package com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway does not exist

These errors appear 6 times in a generated package called `tb2api.TbapiClient.Java`

Looking into this now. (looked, just needed to add `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:<version>'` to gradle.

Comment: Additional notes: Cognito auth is configured for unauthorized access because this database query happens pre-login/signup. Also I select unrestricted access when adding API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue reared its head several times for me over several different projects. I am convinced the correct way to simply `Amplify add api`(REST) with the CLI is not documented anywhere. I refuse to believe that an `IAM` user with `AdministratorAccess-Amplify` permissions cannot successfully administer an Amplify project.

I stumbled upon a better solution. I ran `Amplify configure project` and selected the `Amplify Studio` AWS Profile, which becomes available after enabling Studio in the Amplify console. I could then successfully `Amplify push` my REST API changes. Unfortunately, the `amplifyconfiguration.json` was not being updated with the pushed changes. This caused the Android Compose Authenticator to malfunction, as well as errors when trying to perform a REST operation.

Anyway, I then cleared all the Amplify stuff out of the project folder to start  over. I did an `Amplify pull` on my environment and `amplifyconfiguration.json` was generated, showing all of the resources now. I could successfully authenticate the user and perform a GET operation.

I think an even better solution would be to just provision these resources manually, without the Amplify CLI. I'm fine with how opinionated Amplify is, it just needs to work as expected/documented!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the user that the amplify build is using does not have permission for `apigateway:GET`.

Head over to the tb2-amplify user in IAM and look at the "Permissions policies". You should have a Policy name `AdministratorAccess-Amplify` of type `AWS managed`. That policy as most of the permissions you need for Amplify projects.

If the user doesn't have that policy, add it, or add the individual permissions needed as you encounter them.

This policy should get you to your next error:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": 
            [
              "apigateway:DELETE",
              "apigateway:GET",
              "apigateway:PATCH",
              "apigateway:POST",
              "apigateway:PUT"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**
Another Amplify user [reported an issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/736) that seems the same or extremely similar to what you're experiencing. Try giving your `tb2-amplify` user full permissions and see if that clears up the issue. If it does, you've narrowed this down. Remove the 'full permissions' after deploying and add to the bug description.

**EDIT 2**
If giving the user full access works, then maybe narrow it to just the permissions I put above or the managed policy `AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator`. Those don't have the 'conditional' statement which may make a difference.

I also strongly recommend visiting the [Amplify Discord channel](https://discord.gg/amplify). It's very active.

Comment: The IAM user has AdministratorAccess-Amplify. The policy summary states that "Action": ["apigateway:GET"] is "ALLOW"ed

Comment: are there any next steps here?

Comment: I found a similar bug and updated the answer.

Comment: I was able to ```amplify push``` but when I build the project I get error saying ```package com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation does not exist```

Comment: Yay. So yeah, it's almost certainly the 'condition' in the AWS Amplify managed policy that's causing issues. Use the small policy snippet from my answer above and you're all set until the Amplify policy gets fixed. The 'package does not exist' build error is something new and different. Sorry I can't help with that one.

Comment: I've been fiddling with the latest error, and I just needed to add a dependency in gradle. That is probably not the best solution, but it works and optimizing it is out of scope of this question. I will mark your answer correct as I successfully performed a GET operation. Thanks again.